# How do I center my horizontal list based on a single item in that list?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu, with one of the menu items being a logo. I would like to center the menu so the logo item stays in the center of the page. The goal is to have a menu, split by a logo, that stays centered on the logo. The location of the logo is calculated by number of menu items / 2 + 1 and round down if needed. Example: with 6 menu items, logo is in spot 4; with 5 menu items, logo is in spot 3.

Complications: 1) menu items do not have a set width - this is meant to be responsive, and I am avoiding set pixel widths at every juncture, 2) I do not want to use JavaScript

EDIT: HTML

```
<ul class="nav-menu">
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="/link-1">
            <span>Link 1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-logo">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="http://example.com/">
                <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/581134293931548673/8R33fIjl.png"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="/link-2">
            <span>Link 2</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="/link-3">
            <span>Link 3</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
<style> 
.nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 85%;
}

.nav-menu .menu-item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: .25rem 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

#logo {
    max-width: 15vw;
}

#logo img {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

jsfiddle @ https://jsfiddle.net/szamxv2u/

Comment: Can you post your html and css?

Comment: Post a [mcve] **in your question** please

Comment: I've put the html and css in the original post

Comment: You'll need to put logo (absolutely positioned maybe) between two containers of nav-links. And manually put links in proper containers. But I don't see how this could be responsive (if links length overflow container, they'll drop to second line)

Comment: Ok, so if I put the logo between two nav containers, how do I make sure that the logo is centered in the window with the two nav containers on either side without using JavaScript?

Comment: So far, I've been able to heavily limit my JavaScript use, but if there's a way to avoid using it altogether, I would much prefer that. Any thoughts?